# Semantic Issue "Attempt to use a deleted function" met compiling c++ code with std::thread usage

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm compiling a block of code that contains a

> std::thread::thread(Fp fp&&__, Args &&...__args)

function that, as described in the documentation [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/), performs the following:

> (2) initialization constructor
>       Construct a thread object that represents a new joinable thread of execution.
>       The new thread of execution calls fn passing args as arguments (using decay copies of its lvalue or rvalue references).
>       The completion of this construction synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of this copy of fn.

I suppose this means "the thread will execute function Fn after it is constructed".

However I meet a Semantic Issue during compile time, saying "Attempt to use a deleted function" in the library source file *thread* at the following line:

```
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
```

I'm using LLVM C++ std library with C++ 11 support on XCode, Mac OS. I know this std::thread class is a C++ 11 feature and won't work on C++ 98. Any suggestions for making the code compilable? Pointing out of bad use of the C++ functions or classes is also appreciated.

My code is trying to perform a timerThreadTask each time a port event is received. The timerThreadTask will perform callBackFunc after a given sleep length, but will not do so if next port event happens before the sleep times out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;
thread *timerThread;
bool interrupted = false;

void callBackFunc(int anyParam) {
    // Perform your timeout handling
    cout << "Callback handling with parameter input " << anyParam << endl;
}

void timerThreadTask(int sleepLengthInMilliSec, void *callBackFuncPtr(int anyParam)) {
    // Thread procedures
    int counter = 100;
    int sleepIntervals = sleepLengthInMilliSec / counter;
    while (counter-- > 0) {
        if (interrupted == true) { // Interrupted
            cout << "Sleep interrupted because a new port event is received." << endl;
            interrupted = false;   // Kill thread
            delete timerThread;
            timerThread = NULL;
            return;
        }
        usleep(sleepIntervals);
    }
    callBackFuncPtr(10);   // Timeout, execute callback
}

void onPortEventReceived() {
    // If a message is received in time, then a thread
    // will still be executing. The timer is to be
    // restarted.
    if (timerThread != NULL) {
        interrupted = true;
    }
    int sleepLengthInMilliSec = 1000; // Set timer
    // Starts a timer thread (**** When this line is commented, the compile will success but this will surely be meaningless)
    timerThread = new thread(timerThreadTask, sleepLengthInMilliSec, callBackFunc);
}
```

Comment: I suggest `boost::optional` instead of a pointer. I also suggest making `callBackFuncPtr` a deduced template argument for any callable-with-one-int-argument type. There's also a standard `sleep_for` function, so no need to use the non-portable `usleep`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void timerThreadTask(int sleepLengthInMilliSec, void (*callBackFuncPtr)(int anyParam))
//                                                   ^                ^
```

Without the parentheses, `void *callBackFuncPtr(int anyParam)` is a function type (function taking `int` and returning `void *`) that is then transformed into a function pointer type in a function's parameter list, with the wrong return type (`void *` instead of `void`).